# While loop only returning final result

Tags: javascript

```
while (counterInc < counter) {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('#results').text(counterInc);
    }, 3000);
  counterInc++;
}
```

This code should increment the tag with ID results every 3000 milliseconds instead the while loop is running and returning the final result. For example instead of changing the text to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..n, it is changing the text to n. How would one have the loop update the text field every 1000 milliseconds with each increment instead of only the final result?

Comment: Ahaha the classical JS tricky question. This is a scope issue. To fix you problem you wnat to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.setInterval)

Comment: You are only changing the text of $('#results') every three seconds; you are incrementing the variable much faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
var counterInc = 0;
var counterMax = 10;

var timeoutId = window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#results').text(counterInc++);
    if (counterInc >= counterMax) {
        window.clearInterval(timeoutId);
    }
}, 500);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GufCs/4/

What was happening was you timeout updated the cell every three seconds, however, your loop can run through a ridiculous amount of numbers in 3 seconds, so it's long since complete by the time the function in setTimeout had run.

This will trigger the function every 500ms (change to 3000ms for your purposes) and only then will it increment the counterInc.  Add it clears the Interval when it reaches counterMax.

Comment: Use `clearInterval` not `cancelInterval`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval

Comment: Yeah, fixed, typed from memory.  Oops.  Not sure why the -1 though?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that setTimeout() acts as an "independent thread". You set it and it executes once after the specified amount of time. In the mean time the "main thread" keeps running: so your counter will get increased in the meantime.

Comment: +1 this is the best answer so far as it is the only one with an explanation and not just some code.

Comment: @Razvan, everything here has a downvote, looks like someone was downvoting everthing.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the problem you need to understand what a closure is.
Here you want each time to pass a certain value not the one computed at the end  of the loop scope.

So compute the value at the moment you declare the setTimout rather than when it is call you can do as follow: http://jsfiddle.net/lechevalierd3on/jhYm3/

```
var counter = 10;
var counterInc= 0;

while (counterInc < counter) {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
      var inc = counterInc;
      return function(){
          $('#results').text(inc);
      }
  }(counterInc), 1000 * counterInc);   

  counterInc++;
}​
```

Answer (score -2):

```
while (counterInc < counter) {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('#results').text(counterInc);
    }, 3000 * counterInc++);
}
```